# Unsupported ONNX opset version: 11

Tags: python, pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm following [this](https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4#3-darknet2onnx) guide to `convert darknet to onnx`. However, I'm facing the following error:

> "C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch_yolov4\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\symbolic_helper.py",
> line 253, in _set_opset_version
> raise ValueError("Unsupported ONNX opset version: " + str(opset_version)) ValueError: Unsupported ONNX opset version: 11

What does this error mean and how to deal with it?

Comment: Can you open this file `C:\Users\Scott\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch_yolov4\lib\site-packages\torch\onnx\symbolic_helper.py` via some code editor (like visual studio code) and paste here lines 245 to 260?

Comment: @theQuestionMan, upgrading my pytorch version to 1.6.0 solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an old PyTorch version, probably PyTorch 1.2.

The docs here https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4#4-pytorch2onnx recommend at least PyTorch 1.4.

Comment: Yeah, upgrading was the solution. I upgraded pytorch version to 1.6.0 and now it's working fine. Thanks.